# C#: Read data of Excel's Form Controls

Tags: c#, excel

I need to read data that user inputs into Excel template using C#.

In this template, there are several Form Controls like checkboxes or radio buttons.

Is there anyway I can read data from those controls?

For anyone doesn't know what Excel's Form Controls are, they can be created via Developer tab of Excel like below image:

[Excel's Form Controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1M9E.png)

So I'm not looking for way to read Excel data from Windows Form, please don't misunderstand.

I found out that these Form Controls can be linked to Excel Cells like the image below:

[Link Excel Form Controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCj0Z.png)

and when user changes data of the control, data in the linked cell is also changed.

I can read data in this cell instead.

But I'm looking for another way to read the data because the template is not easily changed and also, I need to migrate thousands of already inputted excel files.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: u generate EXCEL right have some values you want to read from worksheet cell values ?@Cương Cứng

Comment: @jose: sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: u want to read excel cell values ?

Comment: No, I don't. I want to read value of Excel's Form Controls

Comment: @NDC00629 - have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get info from the Ribbon. So you should try to make a new VSTO project to get access to it.
More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772088.aspx and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx